# Categories and subcategories in optgroup

Tags: php, html, optgroup

I want to have a Hierarchical Data in select box with php:

[image]

But when I use [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup), the `<optgroup>` couldnt have a value. 
Is there any way to have a Hierarchical Data like this image?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you mean the optgroup couldnt have a value? Maybe you could add the category to each items value, for example cat1_value1, cat1_value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optgroup isn't selectable either.

I always use indenting with `&nbsp;` to create an hierarchical select box.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this as php but it's not anything to do with PHP.

Optgroups don't have values - [they have labels](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp).

You might want to checkout [phplm](http://phplayersmenu.sourceforge.net/demo.php)